# TJclStringList crashes on Free

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, jedi

Create a simple VCL application:

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
   procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  JclStringLists;

var
  MyList1: TJclStringList;
  MyList2: TJclStringList;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyList1.Free;
  MyList2.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyList1 := TJclStringList.Create;
  MyList2 := TJclStringList.Create;
  MyList1.LoadFromFile('C:\ONE.txt');
  MyList2.LoadFromFile('C:\TWO.txt');
  Self.Caption := Self.Caption + ' ' + IntToStr(MyList1.Count);
  Self.Caption := Self.Caption + ' ' + IntToStr(MyList2.Count);
end;

end.
```

It crashes in the `TForm1.FormDestroy` event-handler when attempting to free the **MyList1** object instance. Why?

Comment: Seems rather implausible. Which version of JCL are you linking?

Comment: What do you mean by 'crashes'? What is the exception raised?

Comment: Did you create multiple instance of TForm1?

Comment: Oh hang on, if there are multiple instances of the form then yes of course this code will fail. Stop using global variables!

Comment: Invalid pointer operation: https://i.imgur.com/PDF2Hgi.png

Comment: Here is the EurekaLog crash report: https://i.imgur.com/Td05KrW.png

Comment: Here are the EurekaLog details: https://i.imgur.com/GueETHN.png

Comment: There are NO multiple instances of the form.

Comment: Here is the EurekaLog Call Stack: https://i.imgur.com/xi9icg1.png

Comment: Weirdly enough, I get the same. The error occurs *after* FormDestroy, so I guess these are somehow lifetime managed with interfaces. No time to check the JCL code right now.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What does "lifetime managed" mean? How can I avoid the crash? Don't I have to free the `TJclStringList` object instance?

Comment: I don't think it uses interfaces to avoid having to free them. But something is weird. As I said, no time to check this. Why don't you debug this, using the JCL sources?

Comment: Confirmed. It also happens if you move the variable declarations from global vars to the private section of the form. However, a quick inspection of JCLStringLists reveals the declaration of `TJCLStringList=class(TJclInterfacedStringList, IInterface, IJclStringList)`, and that it implements `_AddRef` and `_Release` to increment and decrement the reference count, which indicates that it is lifetime managed with interfaces. (Not sure why you couldn't just look at the source yourself.) The reference count means that you simply create them and don't free them; they'll go away when out of scope.

Comment: Actually, a closer inspection of the code shows that you're not supposed to call the constructor at all, but should use `function JclStringList`, which returns a `IJclStringList` interface reference. See the source at approximately line 394, just above the `implementation` keyword.

Comment: @KenWhite but how could I load the text file into MyList1 and MyList 2 if I don't create the MyList1 and MyList2 objects?

Comment: You **do** create them, using the function `JclStringList`. `var MyList1: IJclStringList; begin MyList := JclStringList; MyList.LoadFromFile()`. You simply don't free it when you're finished, which means you don't leave them as global variables because you need to manage the variable scope.

Comment: @KenWhite so is this correct now? https://i.imgur.com/XCwp714.png

Comment: I can't see your image (imgur is blocked by our proxy server). See my answer below for an example of how to do things.

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, your image shows the correct way. For those who can't see it: `MyList1` and `MyList2` are now of type `IJclStringList` and there is no FormDestroy anymore. instead of `MyList1 := TJclStringList.Create;` etc. it is now `MyList1 := JclStringList;`. If you ask me, they could have made this a little clearer by changing the constructor and by giving a better name to the overloaded functions named JclStringList, e.g. NewJclStringList or some such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TJclStringList` is a reference counted type (it's declared in `JCLStringLists.pas` as `type TJclStringList = class(TJclInterfacedStringList, IInterface, IJclStringList)` and implements both `_AddRef` and `_Release` to handle reference counting), so you shouldn't be creating them as objects at all, and you shouldn't manually free them - they will automatically be free'd when the reference to them goes out of scope. (This also means you should not declare them as global variables, because you then don't maintain control over their lifetime.)

The `JclStringLists` unit provides several functions that will properly create an instance of the interface for you. You can see them in that unit, just above the `implementation` keyword:

```
function JclStringList: IJclStringList; overload;
function JclStringListStrings(AStrings: TStrings): IJclStringList; overload;
function JclStringListStrings(const A: array of string): IJclStringList; overload;
function JclStringList(const A: array of const): IJclStringList; overload;
function JclStringList(const AText: string): IJclStringList; overload;
```

The proper way to use `TJclStringList` to do what you want is something like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, JCLStringLists;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    MyList1, MyList2: IJCLStringList;  // Note I and not T in type.
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyList1 := JclStringList;
  MyList1.LoadFromFile('C:\Work\Data\FirstName.txt');
  MyList2 := JclStringList
  MyList2.LoadFromFile('C:\Work\Data\LastName.txt');

  // Only to demonstrate that both files got loaded by the code above.
  Self.Caption := Format('First: %d Last: %d', [MyList1.Count, MyList2.Count]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Do NOT free the JclStringLists here - they will automatically be released when
  // the form is destroyed because the reference count will reach zero (as long as
  // you don't have any other references to those variables, which by putting them into
  // the private section is unlikely.
end;

end.
```